# In a C# program, what is ThePreStub?

Tags: c#, profiling

While profiling a C# application, I see considerable CPU usage in a system (?) method called 'ThePreStub'.  What is this?

Comment: Please show what you have tried and what you found and why that information didn't suffice. The first few web search results for "ThePreStub" explain **a lot** on how the CLR works.

Comment: @CodeCaster -- following your comment I did an experiment and found that if you *Google* for "ThePreStub" you do get a lot of good information.  Unfortunately, I had originally tried searching on my Windows VM with Bing as the default provider and found practically nothing.  Lesson learned.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

See: [CLR Inside out - The Performance Benefits of NGen.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163610.aspx)

> Throughput of NGen-compiled code is lower than that of JIT-compiled
>   code primarily for one reason: cross-assembly references. In
>   JIT-compiled code, cross-assembly references can be implemented as
>   direct calls or jumps since the exact addresses of these references
>   are known at run time. For statically compiled code, **however,
>   cross-assembly references need to go through a jump slot that gets
>   populated with the correct address at run time by executing a method
>   pre-stub.** The method pre-stub ensures, among other things, that the
>   native images for **assemblies referenced by that method are loaded
>   into memory before the method is executed.** The pre-stub only needs
>   to be executed the first time the method is called; it is
>   short-circuited out for subsequent calls. However, every time the
>   method is called, cross-assembly references do need to go through a
>   level of indirection. This is principally what accounted for the 5-10
>   percent drop in throughput for NGen-compiled code when compared to
>   JIT-compiled code.